# remove a re-direct javascript code using firebug?

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript

I have added the following java script:

```
window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
```

Now I cannot edit the same page, since it keeps redirecting.

Is there away of removing it or stopping it for me to be able to edit the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `"?Contents=1"` to your site URL to open the `Maintenance page`

- Select your script / content editor
- click close or delete.

Now you can edit your page.

[image]

Comment: hahh yess :) it works! shame there is no open to edit the current webpart.  Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: you can edit your current web part by clicking close rather than delete. then click add a web part / below category select closed web part , you can find your web part add it , and edit it :) tell me result  :)

Comment: I will click Answered once the seconds have elapsed :) and that "close" and read the app > does not do the trick cos as soon as I add the closed app, it refreshes the site and the redirect kicks back in. ah well